# Disable every network permanently

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have Ubuntu installed on an USB device, I need the system isolated from any network (LAN, wifi, bluetooth, etc.) permanently.

I read a lot of suggestions but some are user-related, other disable only some networks, other are not permanent. After some tests I find a my way, now I am asking if it is correct.

After system installation I prompt the following commands:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/network-manager.conf /etc/init/network-manager.conf.old ;
sudo touch /etc/init/network-manager.conf ;
```

What do you think about?

Comment: If you just want to prevent Network Manager from starting, it's simpler to do `sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override <<<'manual'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the network manager by:

```
sudo apt-get purge networkmanager
```

You can't get more permanent then that...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it in Ubuntu at all. Depending on the device, I'd remove the network hardware or disable it in the BIOS.

Comment: The problem is that often I have to plug the usb in pc where I can't remove hardware or change bios settings, I just want boot from my usb making any change in host pc.

Answer (score 0):

If desired, you can also completely disable the NetworkManager:

```
chkconfig NetworkManager off
chkconfig network on
service NetworkManager stop
service network start
```

Comment: But it starts again after reboot

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create an [upstart script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) that actually executes `rfkill block all` OR you could disable from starting any networking script in `/etc/init` and `/etc/init.d/`. For instance , every script in `/etc/init/` folder has line specifying on which run-levels to run the script. By commenting that line out with `#` you effectively disable the script from starting and thus prevent interfaces from being brought up. There are scripts for bluetooth there as well. Look into it !

Comment: Also , there's [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111258/85039) way

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers, I eventually followed this drastic solution but hopefully definitive

```
sudo apt-get remove -y --purge network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
sudo rm -r /var/lib/NetworkManager
sudo rm -r /etc/NetworkManager
sudo rm -r /etc/network
sudo gedit /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf
```

and in rc-sysinit.conf I replace

```
start on (filesystem and static-network-up) or failsafe-boot
```

with

```
start on (filesystem) or failsafe-boot
```

to avoid boot problem